# How to compare files in listview using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, md5, vb.net-2010

I am fetching files from directories and adding it in list view with their hash values. Now i want to do is compare similar type of files from that list view and display only duplicate files that are present.

I have done this

```
Public Function PrintByteArray(ByRef array() As Byte)
    Dim hex_value As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To array.Length - 1
        hex_value += array(i).ToString("x2")
    Next i

    Return hex_value.ToLower
End Function

Dim SourceDir As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(TextBox1.Text)
    For Each childFile As FileInfo In SourceDir.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(Function(file) file.Extension.ToLower = ComboBox1.SelectedItem)

        Dim hash
        hash = MD5.Create
        Dim hashvalue() As Byte
        Dim filestream = childFile.OpenRead
        hashvalue = hash.ComputeHash(filestream)
        Dim has_hex1 = PrintByteArray(hashvalue)

        'Adding in ListView
        Dim NewItem As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(childFile.Name))
        Dim filesize As Long = childFile.Length / 1024
        Dim fileLocation = childFile.FullName
        NewItem.SubItems.Add(filesize)
        NewItem.SubItems.Add(childFile.Extension)
        NewItem.SubItems.Add(has_hex1)
        NewItem.SubItems.Add(fileLocation)

    Next
```

However this above code only adds the file retrieved from directories. I need to display files that are same in directory.Please do help me on this.

Comment: Does what you have done work? If not, what is the specific issue?  Exactly where does it behave contrary to your expectations? What are those specific expectations and what is the actual behaviour?

Comment: actually the above code is very simple it retrieves files from the directory with its hash value and displays it in list view. Instead i want to get files which are duplicate file with same name and same hash values and display it in list view. I have no clue how to go forward with it could u please help me for the same

Comment: The code will not compile with Option Strict on. We don't have the PrintByteArray Function.

Comment: @Mary Please check out the edited code

Comment: _"i want to get files which are duplicate file with same name and same hash values and display it in list view"_ - Basic way: Create a custom data structure to hold the necessary information, then instantiate an instance of it for every file and add each new instance in a [**`List(Of T)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx). However before adding an item to the list iterate the entire thing and see if it already contains an entry with the same data. If it does, add the list entry and the new item to the `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

I used a Directory Dialog Box to get the directory instead of a text box.

```
Public Class CheckForDuplicateFiles
    Private Sub btnDirectory_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDirectory.Click
        Directory.ShowDialog()
        Dim SelectedDirectory As String = Directory.SelectedPath
        Dim SourceDirectory As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(SelectedDirectory)
        Dim lstFiles As New List(Of FileData)
        For Each childFile As FileInfo In SourceDirectory.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(Function(file) file.Extension.ToLower = cboExtensions.SelectedItem.ToString)
            Dim hash As MD5
            hash = MD5.Create
            Dim hashvalue() As Byte
            Dim filestream = childFile.OpenRead
            hashvalue = hash.ComputeHash(filestream)
            Dim has_hex1 As String = PrintByteArray(hashvalue)
            Dim f As New FileData()
            f.Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(childFile.Name)
            f.Size = childFile.Length
            f.Extension = childFile.Extension
            f.Hash = has_hex1
            f.Location = childFile.FullName
            f.AddedToListView = False
            For i As Integer = 0 To lstFiles.Count - 1
                If lstFiles.Item(i).Hash = f.Hash Then
                    AddToListView(f)
                    f.AddedToListView = True
                    If lstFiles.Item(i).AddedToListView = False Then
                        AddToListView(lstFiles.Item(i))
                        lstFiles.Item(i).AddedToListView = True
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            lstFiles.Add(f)
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub AddToListView(file As FileData)
        'Adding in ListView
        Dim NewItem As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(file.Name)
        NewItem.SubItems.Add(file.Size.ToString)
        NewItem.SubItems.Add(file.Extension)
        NewItem.SubItems.Add(file.Hash)
        NewItem.SubItems.Add(file.Location)
    End Sub
    Private Function PrintByteArray(bytes As Byte()) As String
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        For Each b As Byte In bytes
            sb.Append(b)
        Next
        Return sb.ToString
    End Function
    Public Class FileData
        Public Property Name As String
        Public Property Size As Long
        Public Property Extension As String
        Public Property Hash As String
        Public Property Location As String
        Public Property AddedToListView As Boolean
    End Class
End Class
```